# Find equilibrium solution

Tags: calculus

I am supposed to find the equilibrium solutions for:

$$
\frac{d P(t)}{d t}=0.1 P\left(1-\frac{P}{850}\right)-\frac{1830}{85}
$$
But it looks like there are none. I did the following:

1. Find equilibrium solutions when:
   $$
   \frac{d P(t)}{d t}=0
   $$
2. Simplify:

$$
\frac{-0.1 p^{2}}{850}+0.1 P-\frac{1830}{85}=0
$$
$$
\frac{-p^{2}}{8500}+\frac{850p}{8500}-\frac{183000}{8500}=0
$$
$$
p^{2}-850p+183000=0
$$

3. Use the quadratic formula to solve:
   $$
   \frac{-(-850) \pm \sqrt{(-850)^{2}-4(1)(183000)}}{2(1)}
   $$

Have I done that right? I can find a lot of information about how to find the equilibrium - but not much about equations which seem to have none (finite). And what that means in terms of framing the answer.

Comment: With no equilibrium is there another step to take or explanation to write in the answer?

Comment: You have a small algebra error in the 2nd line of your "Simplify," you should have $\frac{-.01 p^2}{85}$

Comment: As written your equation has no (finite) equilibria. All solutions tend to negative infinity. You can see this by graphing the RHS of your equation; it is always negative.

Comment: @user41592 What is the context of your derivative? Maybe is there a mistake before.

Comment: @mwalth thanks. fixed the algebra.  Double checked the question.  So I guess no finite equilibria.  Thanks.